# Ext.NET HyperlinkColumn not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ext.net

I have a `HyperlinkColumn` in a `GridView` with the following code:

```
Html.X().GridPanel().ID("MyId")
    .View(Html.X().GridView().StripeRows(false))

        .Store(Html.X().Store().AutoLoad(true)
            .Model(Html.X().Model().Fields(
                new ModelField("Name", ModelFieldType.String),
                new ModelField("Id", ModelFieldType.Int)))
            .Proxy(Html.X().AjaxProxy()
                .Url(Url.Action("GetItems", "Home"))
            .Reader(Html.X().JsonReader().RootProperty("data").ReadRecordsOnFailure(false))))

        .ColumnModel(
            x.Column().DataIndex("Name"),
            x.HyperlinkColumn().DataIndexHref("Id").Text("Detail")
                .HrefPattern(Url.Action("Index", "Detail")))
```

and here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = MyFactory.Create();
    return View(viewModel);
}

public ActionResult GetItems()
{
    var test = new Item {Name = "Test dashboard", Id = 42};
    return new StoreResult(new List<Item>() {test});
}
```

It all at least works except that the `HyperlinkColumn` doesn't display. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with respect to that column here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing DataIndex for HyperlinkColumn:

```
Html.X().HyperlinkColumn()
    .DataIndex("Id")
    .DataIndexHref("Id")
    .Text("Detail")
    .HrefPattern(Url.Action("Index", "Detail"))
```